# Can I save some new records in the view and pass to the controller (which some fields are shows in the other table)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save some records to a new table, but some of the records display where in the other table, can I save the new records from the view and pass to the controller? here is the code

```
@model IEnumerable<TrainingHour.Models.LevelPeriod>

@{
    var sInfo=(IEnumerable<TrainingHour.Models.SInfo>)ViewBag.sInfo;
}
```

I want to save the records from sInfo to the LevelPeriod Table

```
    @foreach (var item in staffInfo)
    {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                    </td>
```

the record above where in the sInfo Table

```
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => item.TierId, new SelectList(ViewBag.TierId, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </td>
```

the record above where the info I want to save into the LevelPeriod Table

```
                </tr>
        }
    }
```

the Model of LevelPeriod is as below

```
[Table("LevelPeriod")]
public class LevelPeriod  
{       
    [Key]
    public int SLId { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public int TierId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StaffId")]
    public SInfo SInfo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TierId")]
    public LevelInfo LevelInfo { get; set; }

}
```

how can I use the sInfo information, use view to save the LevelPeriod records to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I hope this what you want ,that is you want to save SInfo table(model)  records into the LevelPeriod  from the view. Correct me if am wrong

For that you can put all the Sinfo form fields into the form and post the records to the controller. In the controller action method transfer object properties from one to another and then save it .

Important Note: you shouldn't use view for save or any other database operations.

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik